# Export Specific Slides as PPTX Presentations

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to break a large presentation up into smaller pptx files. 
I've tried the code below, but I don't think the export function works for pptx. When I run the macro I get `Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005)': Slide (unknown member): Powerpoint can't export the slide(s) because no installed converter supports this file type.`

```
Sub ExportCharts()
Dim savePath As String
Dim End_of_Pop As String


'Input box for End of POP for File Name
End_of_Pop = InputBox("Input End of POP (YYYYMMDD)")


'Create folder for files for sharepoint
MkDir ActivePresentation.Path & "\Week_Ending_" & End_of_Pop

'Export as PPTX
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).Export ActivePresentation.Path & "\Week_Ending_" & End_of_Pop & "\" & End_of_Pop & "_Weekly_AVA_Charts", "pptx"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach instead: For each new pptx needed, duplicate the original pptx and then delete slides as needed. This approach is easy both manually and programmatically. Let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: has the right idea.  But when you step through your slides deleting the ones you don't want to retain, do it backwards ... from highest number to lowest.  If you delete slide 1 first, slide two becomes slide 1 and so on. You'll end up with the wrong slides in your saved presentation.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will help you save the individual slides of your presentation as seperate pptx files.

Just change the following in the code

1. Change `K:\PRESENTATION_YOU_ARE_EXPORTING.pptx` with the file path of the presentation you are exporting.
2. Change `K:\FOLDER PATH WHERE PPTX SHOULD BE EXPORTED\` with the folder path where the exported presentations should be saved.
3. Remember to add \ at the end of the folder path in Step 2.

   ```
   Sub ExportSlidesToIndividualPPPTX()
     Dim oPPT As Presentation, oSlide As Slide
     Dim sPath As String
     Dim oTempPres As Presentation
     Dim x As Long

     ' Location of PPTX File
     Set oPPT = Presentations.Open(FileName:="K:\PRESENTATION_YOU_ARE_EXPORTING.pptx")
     ' Location Where Individual Slides Should Be Saved
     ' Add \ in the end
     sPath = "K:\FOLDER PATH WHERE PPTX SHOULD BE EXPORTED\"

     For Each oSlide In oPPT.Slides
        lSlideNum = oSlide.SlideNumber
        sFileName = sPath & "Slide - " & lSlideNum & ".pptx"
        oPPT.SaveCopyAs sFileName
        ' open the saved copy windowlessly
        Set oTempPres = Presentations.Open(sFileName, , , False)

        ' Delete all slides before the slide you want to save
        For x = 1 To lSlideNum - 1
            oTempPres.Slides(1).Delete
        Next

        ' Delete all slides after the slide you want to save
        For x = oTempPres.Slides.Count To 2 Step -1
            oTempPres.Slides(x).Delete
        Next

        oTempPres.Save
        oTempPres.Close

     Next

     Set oPPT = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```